# C++ setting a value to a enum item inside a class

Tags: c++, enums

my name is Josh and I am trying to make this code work but I could achieve nothing so far... 
Sorry if It is silly and I am wasting your time, I am new to C++ (which I already love), Let me try to explain.

Basicaly what I want to do is insert a enum into a class, set a value to an iten from the enum(class maybe), but I can't access the item to set a value...

eg. Edge of Fight - 24 Physical Damage / 54 Movement Speed / 5 Ability Power.
Sorry for the bad English, it is not my main language...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;






class Enemy {
protected:
    int physicalDamage;
    double moveSpeed;
    int abilityPower;
public:
    void setPhysicalDamage(int p) {
        physicalDamage = p;
    }
    void setMoveSpeed(int m) {
        moveSpeed = m;
    }
    void setAbilityPower(int ap) {
        abilityPower = ap;
    }

    virtual void attack() = 0;
    virtual void ability() = 0;
    virtual void speed() = 0;


};

class Itens: public Enemy {
protected:
    enum class itensID {
        gunnersBreaker,
        hitswamSword,
        fineshotsWrath,
        banesBook,
        infinityStar,
        edgeOfFight,
    };

    itensID iID;
public:

    void setItensID(int r) {

        iID.edgeOfFight = r; // Gives me error, I don't really know a way                 around that... 
    };                      // But basically what I wanna do is marked in     double slashes...
                           // I don't know if I should use pointers for     that, but I tried and it also didn't work...



};

class Ninja : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack() {
        cout << "Hero: Ninja." << endl;
        cout << "Physical Damage:  " << physicalDamage << endl;
    }
    void ability() {
        cout << "Ability Power: " << abilityPower << endl;
    }
    void speed() {
        cout << "Movement Speed: " << moveSpeed << endl;
    }
};

class Monster : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack() {
        cout << "Hero: Monster." << endl;
        cout << "Physical Damage:  " << physicalDamage << endl;
    }
    void ability() {
        cout << "Ability Power: " << abilityPower << endl;
    }
    void speed() {
        cout << "Movement Speed: " << moveSpeed << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Ninja n;
    Monster m;
    Enemy *e1 = &n;
    Enemy *e2 = &m;

    /*

        Find a way to set an enum item to the Ninja hero

                                                            */

    e1->setPhysicalDamage(203);
    e1->setAbilityPower(12);
    e1->setMoveSpeed(321.32);
    e2->setPhysicalDamage(40);
    e2->setAbilityPower(654);
    e2->setMoveSpeed(310.44);

    n.attack();
    n.ability();
    n.speed();
    m.attack();
    m.ability();
    m.speed();
}
```

I've updated the code, but got a error that I am cracking my head trying to fix it. I'll explain what I am trying to do now.

I want the problem to update Hero's current pd,ap,ms with the addition of the gunnersBreak item

**UPDATED CODE!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



struct itensID {
    void gunnersBreaker(int pd, int ap, float ms);
    void hitswamSword(int pd, int ap, float ms);
    void fineshotsWrath(int pd, int ap, float ms);
    void banesBook(int pd, int ap, float ms);
    void infinityStar(int pd, int ap, float ms);
    void edgeOfFight(int pd, int ap, float ms);
};


void itensID::gunnersBreaker(int pd, int ap, float ms)
{
    int physicalDamage = pd;
    int abilityPower = ap;
    float moveSpeed = ms;

    cout << "\n Shotgun: Gunner's Break " << endl;
    cout << "\n Stats:";
}

void itensID::hitswamSword(int pd, int ap, float ms)
{
}

void itensID::fineshotsWrath(int pd, int ap, float ms)
{
}

void itensID::banesBook(int pd, int ap, float ms)
{
}

void itensID::infinityStar(int pd, int ap, float ms)
{
}

void itensID::edgeOfFight(int pd, int ap, float ms)
{
}



class Enemy {
protected:
    int physicalDamage;
    int abilityPower;
    float moveSpeed;

public:
    void setEnemyStatus(int p, int a, float m) {
        physicalDamage = p;
        abilityPower = a;
        moveSpeed = m;
    }

    virtual void attack() = 0;
    virtual void ability() = 0;
    virtual void speed() = 0;


};

                             // Basically what I wanna do now is, add two or     three values to the items eg. gunnersBreaker (int pd, int ap & float ms)
                            // Since I am struggling to get this going, I     have decided to set them as string, just to print while I figure-
                           // out how to add multiple values for a item in a     structure, maybe I should make them a void function instead-
                          // of a regular variable? (I would discard this     since regular variables takes only one identifier, I guess)
                         //  or should I make it a class instead?



class Ninja : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack() {
        cout << "Hero: Ninja." << endl;
        cout << "Physical Damage:  " << physicalDamage << endl;
    }
    void ability() {
        cout << "Ability Power: " << abilityPower << endl;
    }
    void speed() {
        cout << "Movement Speed: " << moveSpeed << endl;
    }
};

class Monster : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack() {
        cout << "Hero: Monster." << endl;
        cout << "Physical Damage:  " << physicalDamage << endl;
    }
    void ability() {
        cout << "Ability Power: " << abilityPower << endl;
    }
    void speed() {
        cout << "Movement Speed: " << moveSpeed << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Ninja n;
    Monster m;
    Enemy *e1 = &n;
    Enemy *e2 = &m;
    itensID iID;

    /*
        on the lines below ptr1 and ptr2, I got kind of an error, 
        I got to find a way to calculate the Enemy Status with the addition     of the item specs
        and print out the item I am using, EG. Hero: Ninja!
                                             Weapon: Gunner's Breaker.
                                             Stats.... and so on...
                                                                                            */

    e1->setEnemyStatus(35,10,310.21) + iID.gunnersBreaker(33,11,32.32); //     ptr1
    e2->setEnemyStatus(54,65,235.30);                                  //     ptr2

    n.attack();
    n.ability();
    n.speed();
    m.attack();
    m.ability();
    m.speed();
}
```

Comment: [Off Topic] Why does Item derive from enemy?  An item shouldn't be an enemy.

Comment: [On Topic] Why not make the enum global, or at least public, so you can have the enumeration passed to the function instead of an `int`?

Comment: [Off Topic] maybe its a cursed sentient object.  Forget it, he's rolling.

Comment: It seems that `class` becomes very confusing when used with `enum`. `edgeOfFight` and other enum items are not class fields and it is not possible to assign anything to them.

Comment: [On Topic] why not `void setItensID( intensID r )`   ?

Comment: @Ghosterrify No, there is no access right to worry about.  You cannot assign to an  enumeration value, only an enumeration object.  `itensID foo = itensID::gunnersBreaker;` is OK.  `itensID::gunnersBreaker = itensID::edgeOfFight` will be a compiler error.

Comment: @infixed I'll do that, but maybe i'll have to work this program from the ground, seems confusing for me... Atleast for what I want to do, eg. Have an item, set pd,ms,ap and be able to use the item on a hero, thanks for the help everyone, I really appreciate!

Comment: @NathanOliver, Thanks, it looks better as a global enum, in a class it was really a mess, I gotta get more into enums, i'll have to find a way to work around it, maybe using normal classes with variables instead of enum items?... Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @VTT, I guess I have to make a normal class and add a bunch of itens in there? I'll look forward to do that and see the outcome, thanks or the help by the way!

Comment: @NathanOliver, sorry to bother you, I have updated the code, I don't know if I should toggle it as unsolved since the problem is solved, but here I go again annoying you :( sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are trying to use your `enum` like `struct` and assign value to one of its element. `enums` are list of named values which can be used to represent some values (like i.e. flags or states) that are unhandy and/or unsafe to represent by arithmetic types.
Your `itensID iID` is a variable of your `itensID` enum class type, so you can assign to it one of named values which you listed in `itensID` enum class body (i.e. `iID = itensID::edgeOfFight`).

Comment: thanks! I am going to make some changes on the code, I will have to check some struct forms to get those itens working, again, thanks for the help, I really appreciate!

Comment: sorry to bother you, I've updated the code... Could you take a look at it ? I need some help :(

Comment: thankyou for answering, I thought I had a good base to start a program of that type, but it seems that I am not even close... By the way, thanks for the suggestion, i'm going to start reading the book right now!